# links not clickable after using pseudo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i got problem, i created hover animation for border, but problem here is that all links (a href's) that are in that DIV aren't clickable after animation is over, is there way to exclude them or do something to make that clickable at all times?

### [Here is a Codepen](https://codepen.io/nikolamilovac/pen/ppMQPv)

All comments are much appreciated, thanks in advance.

so this is my structure setup

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 image-cover">
<div class="first">
<div class="read-more">
<a href="">read more>>></a></div>
<div class="date">
<p>date</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

style is big so i can't paste it here, if you can check codepen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo-elements are being drawn over your links, so you're actually clicking the pseudo and not the links bellow.

You need add either pointer-events:none; or z-index:-1 to your pseudo-elements

```
.first {
  &::before,
  &::after {
    pointer-events:none;
    /* OR */
    z-index:-1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow you are both right and it was that simple, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your pseudo elements are drawing over your original element, so if you mouse over the links, you're actually just mousing over your `::before` and `::after`. A simple fix would be to add the following line to your pseudo selectors:

```
&:hover::before,
&:hover::after {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This makes the mouse ignore those elements, allowing clicks below on your links.

More about `pointer-events`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Wow you are both right and it was that simple, thank you!